# External URL with image

Tags: url

I want to have the option to have social media icons that will link to different URLs. I currently have it set up so the user can click which icons will display on the page, but how would I have it so they can change the link to what URL they want?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're on the right path. Create a Global matrix field containing an asset field for Social Icon, a text field for Social Url, and a lightswitch field for Enabled/Disabled. Then the user can add new social media icons as needed and manipulate the url.

Answer (score 1):

Many, many possible ways to go about this, but the simplest would be to create a [Plain Text field](https://craftcms.com/docs/plain-text-fields) in the control panel and call it something like "Social Media Link" with a handle of "socialMediaLink" and give it some field instructions along the lines of "Enter the URL for the social media button".

Attach that to the field layout for your [section](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries).

When your client edits the entry for that section, then can enter whatever URL they want.

Your template would display it something like:

```
<a href="{{ entry.socialMediaLink }}"><img src="mySocialMediaButton.jpg"></a>
```